# Count number of Views/Hits

Tags: python, django

Here's the code,

```
class Music(models.Model):
    visits = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

def music(request)
    ......
```

Though it's not a good way of doing it but how can I increase 'visits' by +1 whenever view 'music' is requested ?

Please help me, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seems a bit more than your needs, you could use though the **[django-hitcount](https://github.com/thornomad/django-hitcount)** app. It's very easy to use and it also has more goodies: for how long a hit will be active, exclude hits from users of a specified group, the possibility to limit the number of active hits from a single IP address, etc. (Also it has a very good [documentation](http://django-hitcount.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we will find out number of visits that are saved in database

```
visits = Music.objects.all().values_list('visits', flat=True)
```

and then increment the field by 1

```
visits += 1
```

and then simply save this value in your db.